# sending mail using Amazon SES and display stats of mail using Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I want to setup SES for sending mails in bulk using Laravel 5.4 and I want to see it's stats like soft bounce, hard bounce, clicks, opens, etc information and display this information in my admin panel.

I read some docs of amazon and it's not up to mark so can anyone please help me to get nice tutorial which fulfils my needs above mentioned

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try out Aws API to get status of your email being send.
And if you want to get bounce and complaints you can create a API from your side and add those in AWS panel by creating topics and also you have to verify these, or else there are other methods described in AWS Dashboard.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/handling-bounces-and-complaints/